# Access 2016 - Filtro multiple con ComboBoxes en cascada

Tags: ms-access, combobox, filtro

este es mi primer post así que probablemente cometa algún error al redactarlo, si es así o si falta algún dato necesario para ayudarme a resolver mi problema por favor díganmelo.

Estoy realizando una base de datos en Access 2016 y es mi primera vez usando vba, hasta el momento no se me había complicado nada, pero llegue al punto en el que despues de 3 horas de revisar el código no pude encontrar solución a mi problema, la situación es esta:

En mi base de datos tengo un formulario (search_container) que a su vez contiene un subformulario (search_results) en Vista hoja de datos, el formulario utiliza combos en cascada para filtrar lo que se muestra en el subformulario, los combos filtran los datos de UNIDAD(searchbox_unit), SERVICIO(searchbox_dept),AÑO(searchbox_year) y MES(searchbox_month), la cosa es que en los combos searchbox_unit, searchbox_dept y searchbox_year mi código funciona de maravilla pero al llegar al combo searchbox_month este simplemente no hace nada. El código del filtro lo tengo así:

```
Private Sub FilterSubform()
    Dim strWhere As String

    If Nz(Me.searchbox_unit, "") <> "" Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "[UNIDAD] = '" & Me.searchbox_unit & " ' AND "
    End If

    If Nz(Me.searchbox_dept, "") <> "" Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "[SERVICIO] = '" & Me.searchbox_dept & " ' AND "
    End If

    If Nz(Me.searchbox_year, "") <> "" Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "[AÑO] = " & Me.searchbox_year & "  AND "
    End If

    If Nz(Me.searchbox_month, "") <> "" Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "[MES] = '" & Me.searchbox_month & " ' AND "
    End If

    If strWhere <> "" Then
        strWhere = Left(strWhere, Len(strWhere) - 5)
        Me.search_results.Form.Filter = strWhere
        Me.search_results.Form.FilterOn = True
    Else
        Me.search_results.Form.Filter = ""
        Me.search_results.Form.FilterOn = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Por cierto el código esta en (General) y se ejecuta en el evento AfterUpdate de cada uno de los combos mediante `Call FilterSubform` y solo agregué algunos Requerys a los demás combos. Por ejemplo:

```
Private Sub searchbox_year_AfterUpdate()
    Forms!search_container.searchbox_month = ""
    Forms!search_container.searchbox_month.Requery
    Call FilterSubform

End Sub

Private Sub searchbox_month_AfterUpdate()
    Call FilterSubform

End Sub
```

Me imagino que debe de ser alguna burrada que pase por alto pero ya me harte de buscarla espero me puedan ayudar. Muchas gracias.

PD. Disculpen los nombres de los combos pero ya tenia demasiados con nombre cbo*** en otros formularios.

Comment: El campo `MES` es un campo de texto o es numérico?

Comment: El campo MES es texto

Answer (score 0):

Ok, entiendo que es un filtro en cascada, Selecciona primero la "Unidad", luego el "Servicio", despues el "Año" y al final el "Mes", solo que veo un detalle, a tu concatenacion le hace falta el "SELECT", solo estas concatenando 'strWhere' y al final depuras la misma cadena, y la pones en el evento.